# Find two maximum points

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a two arrays that I plot: `A` a 1x101 vector and `B` the same

```
A = [0.140673450903833  0.143148937279028   0.145430952171596   0.147474938627147   0.149581060870114   0.151187105347571   0.152646348246015   0.153892222566265   0.154913060187075   0.155701930397674   0.156253328260122   0.156562551841967   0.156625533585493   0.156438787610539   0.155999394209637   0.155304997895017   0.154353810555534   0.153144616301392   0.151676776486360   0.149950234280632   0.147965519042205   0.145723755995511   0.143229676241241   0.140476287800831   0.137475884805212   0.134228713435530   0.130738812449387   0.127010778531129   0.123049766057659   0.118861478234099   0.114452155847321   0.109828564345449   0.104997979409803   0.0999681710919947  0.0947473865690700  0.0893443315667412  0.0837681505026921  0.0780284054055798  0.0721350536699391  0.0660984247128685  0.0599291956061627  0.0536383657701255  0.0472372308396036  0.0407373558685518  0.0341505481893574  0.0274888307202605  0.0207644183921863  0.0139897104812690  0.00717740846258673 0.000358034181698980    0.00651349557333709 0.0133637955715171  0.0202018404602034  0.0270147225489001  0.0337898204971252  0.0405146415132138  0.0471768260462406  0.0537641715916784  0.0602646603043279  0.0666664873507057  0.0729580891146200  0.0791281709097673  0.0851657340195109  0.0910601019446384  0.0968009457657087  0.102378308539557   0.107782628657363   0.113004762097380   0.118036003510261   0.122868106079509   0.127493300104313   0.131904310257409   0.136094371477732   0.140057243469708   0.143787223810476   0.147279159770258   0.150528459504324   0.153531108836772   0.156280444813554   0.158783035106175   0.161027296288627   0.163014562505352   0.164743731117677   0.166214276765471   0.167426257040343   0.168380310331524   0.169077651806683   0.169520068571722   0.169709914896378   0.169650109087113   0.169344135453180   0.168796059816963   0.168010582212876   0.166993205517562   0.165750858213848   0.164295206012858   0.162692813100379   0.160590402150861   0.158550181408264   0.156271984944015   0.153800366335689]

B = [-2 -1.96000000000000   -1.92000000000000   -1.88000000000000   -1.84000000000000   -1.80000000000000   -1.76000000000000   -1.72000000000000   -1.68000000000000   -1.64000000000000   -1.60000000000000   -1.56000000000000   -1.52000000000000   -1.48000000000000   -1.44000000000000   -1.40000000000000   -1.36000000000000   -1.32000000000000   -1.28000000000000   -1.24000000000000   -1.20000000000000   -1.16000000000000   -1.12000000000000   -1.08000000000000   -1.04000000000000   -1  -0.960000000000000  -0.920000000000000  -0.880000000000000  -0.840000000000000  -0.800000000000000  -0.760000000000000  -0.720000000000000  -0.680000000000000  -0.640000000000000  -0.600000000000000  -0.560000000000000  -0.520000000000000  -0.480000000000000  -0.440000000000000  -0.400000000000000  -0.360000000000000  -0.320000000000000  -0.280000000000000  -0.240000000000000  -0.200000000000000  -0.160000000000000  -0.120000000000000  -0.0800000000000001 -0.0400000000000000 0   0.0400000000000000  0.0800000000000001  0.120000000000000   0.160000000000000   0.200000000000000   0.240000000000000   0.280000000000000   0.320000000000000   0.360000000000000   0.400000000000000   0.440000000000000   0.480000000000000   0.520000000000000   0.560000000000000   0.600000000000000   0.640000000000000   0.680000000000000   0.720000000000000   0.760000000000000   0.800000000000000   0.840000000000000   0.880000000000000   0.920000000000000   0.960000000000000   1   1.04000000000000    1.08000000000000    1.12000000000000    1.16000000000000    1.20000000000000    1.24000000000000    1.28000000000000    1.32000000000000    1.36000000000000    1.40000000000000    1.44000000000000    1.48000000000000    1.52000000000000    1.56000000000000    1.60000000000000    1.64000000000000    1.68000000000000    1.72000000000000    1.76000000000000    1.80000000000000    1.84000000000000    1.88000000000000    1.92000000000000    1.96000000000000    2];
```

Plotting these two `plot(B,A)` I get this
[image]
with two maximum points at B = -1.52 and B = +1.52

I want to add automatically a point as marker in the two maximum values, a horizontal line above the highest point and a two way row pointing from the line to the second peak like this

[image]

I tried to sort `A` and find the position of the two maximum

```
[val ind] = sort(A,'descend');
max_values = val(1:2)
index = ind(1:2)
r_max = A(ind(1:2))
```

but the second peak is not the the second position of `val` because I get this sort:

```
  Columns 1 through 13

    0.1697    0.1697    0.1695    0.1693    0.1691    0.1688    0.1684    0.1680    0.1674    0.1670    0.1662    0.1658    0.1647

  Columns 14 through 26

    0.1643    0.1630    0.1627    0.1610    0.1606    0.1588    0.1586    0.1566    0.1566    0.1564    0.1563    0.1563    0.1563
```

The first value `0.1697` (in this case) is the correct one, but the second peak is not in the second position but at the 22nd position.

Looking at the plot, how can I get easily the two maximum points? 
Once I know the two coordinates I can easily add all the objects that I need.

Comment: derivative equal to zero?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Then you'll likely also get the minimum, won't you?

Comment: @HansHirse and distinguishing a minimum from a maximum is simple checking the values of its neighbors, not the end of the world ;)

Comment: @AnderBiguri Of course not - I just wanted to point that out, before follow up questions regarding that issue arise. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [findpeaks](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html) (requires Signal Processing Toolbox), [yline](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yline.html) (introduced in R2018b) and [annotation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html) :

```
A = [0.140673450903833  0.143148937279028   0.145430952171596   0.147474938627147   0.149581060870114   0.151187105347571   0.152646348246015   0.153892222566265   0.154913060187075   0.155701930397674   0.156253328260122   0.156562551841967   0.156625533585493   0.156438787610539   0.155999394209637   0.155304997895017   0.154353810555534   0.153144616301392   0.151676776486360   0.149950234280632   0.147965519042205   0.145723755995511   0.143229676241241   0.140476287800831   0.137475884805212   0.134228713435530   0.130738812449387   0.127010778531129   0.123049766057659   0.118861478234099   0.114452155847321   0.109828564345449   0.104997979409803   0.0999681710919947  0.0947473865690700  0.0893443315667412  0.0837681505026921  0.0780284054055798  0.0721350536699391  0.0660984247128685  0.0599291956061627  0.0536383657701255  0.0472372308396036  0.0407373558685518  0.0341505481893574  0.0274888307202605  0.0207644183921863  0.0139897104812690  0.00717740846258673 0.000358034181698980    0.00651349557333709 0.0133637955715171  0.0202018404602034  0.0270147225489001  0.0337898204971252  0.0405146415132138  0.0471768260462406  0.0537641715916784  0.0602646603043279  0.0666664873507057  0.0729580891146200  0.0791281709097673  0.0851657340195109  0.0910601019446384  0.0968009457657087  0.102378308539557   0.107782628657363   0.113004762097380   0.118036003510261   0.122868106079509   0.127493300104313   0.131904310257409   0.136094371477732   0.140057243469708   0.143787223810476   0.147279159770258   0.150528459504324   0.153531108836772   0.156280444813554   0.158783035106175   0.161027296288627   0.163014562505352   0.164743731117677   0.166214276765471   0.167426257040343   0.168380310331524   0.169077651806683   0.169520068571722   0.169709914896378   0.169650109087113   0.169344135453180   0.168796059816963   0.168010582212876   0.166993205517562   0.165750858213848   0.164295206012858   0.162692813100379   0.160590402150861   0.158550181408264   0.156271984944015   0.153800366335689];    
B = [-2 -1.96000000000000   -1.92000000000000   -1.88000000000000   -1.84000000000000   -1.80000000000000   -1.76000000000000   -1.72000000000000   -1.68000000000000   -1.64000000000000   -1.60000000000000   -1.56000000000000   -1.52000000000000   -1.48000000000000   -1.44000000000000   -1.40000000000000   -1.36000000000000   -1.32000000000000   -1.28000000000000   -1.24000000000000   -1.20000000000000   -1.16000000000000   -1.12000000000000   -1.08000000000000   -1.04000000000000   -1  -0.960000000000000  -0.920000000000000  -0.880000000000000  -0.840000000000000  -0.800000000000000  -0.760000000000000  -0.720000000000000  -0.680000000000000  -0.640000000000000  -0.600000000000000  -0.560000000000000  -0.520000000000000  -0.480000000000000  -0.440000000000000  -0.400000000000000  -0.360000000000000  -0.320000000000000  -0.280000000000000  -0.240000000000000  -0.200000000000000  -0.160000000000000  -0.120000000000000  -0.0800000000000001 -0.0400000000000000 0   0.0400000000000000  0.0800000000000001  0.120000000000000   0.160000000000000   0.200000000000000   0.240000000000000   0.280000000000000   0.320000000000000   0.360000000000000   0.400000000000000   0.440000000000000   0.480000000000000   0.520000000000000   0.560000000000000   0.600000000000000   0.640000000000000   0.680000000000000   0.720000000000000   0.760000000000000   0.800000000000000   0.840000000000000   0.880000000000000   0.920000000000000   0.960000000000000   1   1.04000000000000    1.08000000000000    1.12000000000000    1.16000000000000    1.20000000000000    1.24000000000000    1.28000000000000    1.32000000000000    1.36000000000000    1.40000000000000    1.44000000000000    1.48000000000000    1.52000000000000    1.56000000000000    1.60000000000000    1.64000000000000    1.68000000000000    1.72000000000000    1.76000000000000    1.80000000000000    1.84000000000000    1.88000000000000    1.92000000000000    1.96000000000000    2];
plot(B,A)

% Find peaks.
[maxValuesY,isMaxY]=findpeaks(A);
maxValuesX = B(isMaxY);

% Plot horizontal line.
yline(maxValuesY(2));

% Create arrow.
ar = annotation('arrow');
ar.Parent = gca;
ar.X = [maxValuesX(1), maxValuesX(1)];
ar.Y = [maxValuesY(2), maxValuesY(1)];
ar.Color = 'black';
ar.HeadLength = 3;
```

[image]

Thanks to [marsei](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36290706/3390419) for tip on the position of annotation.

Comment: That's what I've used in the first place, but then I decided to not to rely on the availability of certain toolboxes. Nevertheless, for finding local extrema, `findpeaks` is a better choice than my solution.

Comment: Is it possible to make the arrow disappear automatically if the two peaks are on the same line (same level)? Without using if conditions.

Answer (score 4):

If you specifically have such plots, you can go with the following solution, which just excludes `n` neighbours around the first found maximum.

```matlab
% Input (copy from above...)
A = [ .. ];
B = [ .. ];

% Index of max value.
[max_val, max_idx] = max(A);

% Find second max value by excluding n neighbourhood.
n = 10;
AA = A;
AA(max_idx - n : max_idx + n) = [];
sec_max_val = max(AA);
sec_max_idx = find(A == sec_max_val);

% Output.
figure(1);
hold on;

% Graph.
plot(B, A);

% Black line.
plot([B(1) B(end)], [max_val max_val], 'k');

% Black arrow.
p1 = [B(sec_max_idx) B(sec_max_idx)];
p2 = [max_val sec_max_val];
dp = p2 - p1;
quiver(p1(1), p2(1), p1(2) - p1(1), p2(2) - p2(1), 0, 'k'); 

hold off;
```

You'll get such an output:

[image: Output]